# How do I parse name-value pairs from the set-cookie header?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, parsing

I'm looking for a clean way to parse out 2 variables from the the set-cookie header in an httpwebrequest object.

The string in the Set-Cookie header is as follows:

```
X-Mapping-dmogknml=6652DD088AB10EE6A65DD9C700872364;
path=/,ASP.NET_SessionId=f4jg1h55eoqbdk452blsozfl; path=/;
HttpOnly,id=111,status=rejected; expires=Thu, 21-Mar-2013 07:31:55 GMT; path=/,statusDes=
Validation Failed ; expires=Thu, 21-Mar-2013 07:31:55 GMT; path=/,X-Mapping
dmogknml=dmogknml=6652DD088AB10EE6A65DD9C700872; path=/
```

I basically want to parse out "rejected" from "status=rejected" and "validation failed" from "statusDes=Validation Failed" into 2 string variables.  I've worked out 2 solutions in my head but they seem kinda clunky:

1. Looping and Splitting on ";", then split on ",", then split on "=".
2. Using substring.

Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  However, the question I should have asked was "Why isn't the response.Cookies() object being populated?"  I found out from another question that you have to initialize the CookieContainer of the request, and now I can access these variables simply by using: req.Cookies("status") and req.Cookies("statusDes")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx) that takes a collection of `Char`.

```
 var values = theCookie.Split(new [] {';', ',', '='}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can then loop through the `values` two at a time, looking for the keys to fetch the values, or you can convert to a dictionary first (using LINQ `ToDictionary`).

Comment: Ugh. I'm an idiot.. I figured out what my real problem was.  I wasn't initializing the CookieContainer on the request object, which is why I couldn't pull these values using req.Cookies().  This however is a nice alternate solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Please note ',' will split the expiration timestamp as well.

You can work around this by using Regex.Split with ",(?=[^ ])" for separating the different cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).

This should do it (VB code):

```
Dim Pattern As String = "status=(?<Status>.*?);.*?statusDes=(?<StatusDes>.*?);"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input:=MyData, pattern:=Pattern , options:=RegexOptions.IgnoreCase + RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim Status as String
Dim StatusDes as String

    Status = m.Groups("Status").ToString
    StatusDes = m.Groups("StatusDes").ToString
```

Remember to import `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Hope tihs helps!